# .NET Core Web API Buggy Issue In IIS with 404 and Request Not Reaching Code

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm really struggling with weird issues with WebAPI and .NET Core 2.0 running in IIS.  Weird issues I've never ever had with WebAPI and .NET.

Take this issue for example.  I have a very simple WebAPI with a simple routing and a simple GET method.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/ProductData")]
public class ProductDataController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
    {
         return Ok();
    }
}
```

If I make a REST request, every single REST request I make will succeed except for one specific one.  Every possible combination you can come up with will succeed.  All of these succeed:

```
/api/productdata/product-317
/api/productdata/product-317dasdasd3
/api/productdata/product-31asd73
/api/productdata/product-173
/api/productdata/product-373
/api/productdata/product-373
/api/productdata/product-3174
```

Except for the following - this fails with a 404 - every time:

```
/api/productdata/product-3173
```

This fails everytime and gives me a 404 error without even executing the code in visual studio.  All of the other combinations above execute the code and hit the breakpoint.  But, /api/productdata/product-3173 never hits the breakpoint and instead gives me a 404.  Every single time.  I've rebooted.  I really have no idea what to do to fix this other than drop .NET Core completely.

I check the IIS logs, and it shows that the requests are being recorded there and a 404 is generated.  I've tried multiple clients including Postman, Chrome, and IE.  Same behaviour everytime with every client.

I'm really torn up about how to fix this.  It's just not anything that makes any sense to me.  There is no custom routing that is interfering here either.  I don't even know how to continue debugging this.  There is nothing in the event log about it.

There is no custom routing in Startup.cs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace TRVL.Rest
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `{id}` portion of the route and pass the value as querystring?

Comment: Sure.  That works of course.  It's only prejudiced against this URI /api/productdata/product-3173 - every other single possible thing works as it should.

Comment: Okay what about if you add a / at the end of uri

Comment: Any non-default routing in `Startup.cs`?

Comment: That works in all cases except for the one I indicated.  api/productdata/product-3173/ <-- 404 (Always 404 with this) ....   api/productdata/product-3173everythingelse/ <--200 Works

Comment: No non-default routing in Startup.cs --> I've modified the post to show the full code for your reference.

Comment: Something weird is going on.  I put a bunch of garbage in the web.config which would force any request to the application to crash, and of course api/productdata/product-3173 CRASHED with the web.config error.  All of the other requests (ex: api/productdata/product-317asdasd) worked and the breakpoint was hit in Visual Studio.  So, for some reason, some URI's are using the web.config and others are not although they are in the same app and same IIS application and instance.  Weird.  Still working through this as it's very strange.

Comment: If I change the name of ProductDataController to ProductDataAController, then everything works correctly when calling api/productdataa/product-3173 OR api/productdataa/product-3173 ....  if I call the original api/productdata/product-3173 I still get the problem - now the web.config error as per previous comment (which is weird because this controller is completely gone) , but if I try one of the original URI which used to work, they fail since the controller no longer exists.  Something rouge has happened with IIS as it is handling this specific URI different from every other request

Comment: Resolved it.  I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue.  I found the applicationHost.config file and found the following entry:

```
        <application path="/Product.Rest/api/productdata/product-3173" applicationPool="DefaultAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Product.Rest" />
        </application>
```

This was interfering with all of the requests going to this URI as it was running this under the context of it's own app/virtual directory.

Visual Studio 2017 created this entry automatically without me realizing it.  Also, this DOES NOT show up in IIS as an App or Virtual Directory, so you would not even know it was there unless you searched applicationHosts file directly in which it shows up in the XML only.

Comment: "Visual Studio 2017 created this entry automatically without me realizing it" I don't believe it.